# DotNetOpenAuth to authorize users via Gmail

Tags: oauth

I am using OAuth in my MVC Web Application.  I have installed DotNetOpenAuth using Nuget. This adds all the necessary dlls to my references folder.

I came to know that I need to register the application in the API console as described in [this document](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios). On the Google APIs website, I clicked on "API Access" and create a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I set the application type as being "Web Application" and provide the website name.

After creating a new Client ID I see a page which gives me the following details:

1. Client ID
2. Email address
3. Client secret
4. Redirect URIs
5. JavaScript origins

Now I want to write some code to authenticate a user via Google and list their details, i.e. email address/username. What is the next step? How are DotNetOpenAuth and the Google APIs console connected?

Is there any code that I can look at to point me in the right direction? I've had a look at [this article](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/) which talks about authorizing through LinkedIn. Is there a similar example using Google?